# Copy Table from SQL Server Express to Access MDB in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, copy

Can't get this query to work for some reason

```
SELECT * INTO TableName 
FROM [ODBC;Driver=SQL Server;Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DBName;Trusted_Connection=Yes;].[TableName]
```

Keep getting Error :

> {"ODBC--connection to 'SQL Serverlocalhost\SQLEXPRESS' failed."}

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **please** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Create a linked table in access file and then with simple query you can insert to access table. Use following code to create a linked table in access.

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", _
                               "ODBC;Driver=SQL Server;Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DBName;Trusted_Connection=Yes;",_
                               acTable, "dbo.[tablename", "tablename"
```

If can't create a linked table then try changing the connection string.

Comment: I am not using VBA.  This is a VB.NET application.

Comment: I think you still can create a linked table in mdb file and then copy the data (with vb.net) ...

Answer (score 0):

Very old post but this is simple and it works

```
Dim AccConn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + DBPath)

Dim AccessCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * INTO [NewTableName] FROM [ODBC; Driver=SQL Server;Server=...;Database=...;Trusted_Connection=yes].[TableNameOnSQLServer]", AccConn)
```

Comment: Sorry and add AccessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() for doing the job :)